# Same target IP address when using tsocks

Tags: tsocks

I need to use tsocks (to tunnel an ssh connection through an ssh tunnel to reach given machines), but there is a problem. There are two servers that has the same IP address (that I need to reach through ssh tunnels). So the config for this situation would look like this:

```
cat /etc/tsocks.conf
path {
    reaches = 10.1.1.2/255.255.255.255
    server = 127.0.0.1
    server_port = 3000
}

path {
    reaches = 10.1.1.2/255.255.255.255
    server = 127.0.0.1
    server_port = 2000
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two `tsocks.conf`, one for each SOCKS server and then use them as:

```
TSOCKS_CONF_FILE=~/.tsocks-A.conf tsocks some-cmd 10.1.1.2
```

and

```
TSOCKS_CONF_FILE=~/.tsocks-B.conf tsocks some-cmd 10.1.1.2
```

Alternatively, if the SOCKS servers support SOCKS4A or SOCKS5, you could use `dante`'s `socksify` instead of `tsocks` and use host names if they have different host name on the remote ends (and specify which SOCKS server to use based on host names or domain names in `dante.conf`).

Comment: I can't use hostnames in tsocks?

Comment: @gaskopeter. You can use hostnames, but they will be resolved locally, not on the remote end, and all tsocks will ever see is the IP address that those hostnames resolve to (contrary to dante, tsocks doesn't hijack the hostname resolving functions)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you may be able to do everything, all of it through SSH config files. This is especially true if you're just SSHing to the end machines. See the [SSH multihop config](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html). With appropriately established SSH configs you could just assign destination names and type `ssh servera` or `ssh serverb`, instead of having to set up an SSH tunnel and then type `tsocks ssh servera`.

Tsocks really can't differentiate what you want. One approach would be to set up two config files and issue commands to swap configs for each network

eg:

`$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tsocksa.sh`

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/tsocksa.sh
#!/bin/bash  
#
#Swaps for Network A
#See /etc/tsocs.conf.main and /etc/tsocks.conf.dest_a
#
sudo cat /etc/tsocks.conf{.main,.dest_a} > /etc/tsocks.conf
```

and

`$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tsockss.sh`

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/tsockss.sh  
#!/bin/bash  
#
#Swaps for Network S
#See /etc/tsocks.conf.main and /etc/tsocks.conf.dest_s
#
sudo cat /etc/tsocks.conf{.main,.dest_s} > /etc/tsocks.conf
```

Now you would put your network-swap specific commands into `/etc/tsocks.conf.dest_n` and put your generic networks into `/etc/tsocks.conf.master`

You could also use Bash aliases for the same commands, or further simplify the Bash script into a function you can source in your bashrc.